# Simulate 'this' pointer in matlab

Tags: matlab, this, function-handle

I have a class that encapsulates access to an array in a wierd way;
The class constructor takes a function handle which is some kind of transformation of indexes before passing them to the array

```
classdef MyClass
properties
    arr
    accessHandle
end
methods
function obj = MyClass(array, trans)
    obj.arr = array;
    obj.accessHandle = @(i) obj.arr(trans(i))
end
end
```

The problem is the anonymous function copies the array into it's own workspace and if we change the array, it doesn't change in the function.
Essentially what is needed is to pass to the anonymous function the 'this' pointer/reference like in Java/C++/etc

The simple solution is to create a handle to the array and pass it along to the function:

```
classdef MyClass
properties
    arr
    accessHandle
end
methods
function obj = MyClass(array, trans)
    obj.arr = array;
    tmp = PropertyReference(obj, 'arr'); %See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085588/matlab-create-reference-handle-to-variable 
    %for the definition
    obj.accessHandle = @(i) tmp(trans(i));
end
end
end
```

The problem now is when I pass an instance of the class to a function, the reference passed still refers to the object outside the function:

```
function foo(ins)
    ins.arr = [1 2];
    disp(ins.accessHandle(1));
end
cl = MyClass([0 3], @(x) x);
foo(cl) //output 0 instead of 1
disp(ins.accessHandle(1)) //output 0
```

**EDIT:** The class should be a value class, the semantics are that when a copy of the class is made, the `accessHandle` field changes the array handle it uses.

How can I achieve the right semantics ?

Comment: Would subclassing `handle` fix this?

Comment: @TroyHaskin @Suever I can't make it a handle like I explained in the last sentance; `foo` does not change the input, only it's copy

Comment: The equivalent C++ definition of `accessHandle` would be `[this](int x){return this->arr(trans(x));}` if that helps

Comment: You're not making `arr` a handle; you're making `MyClass` a `handle` class object which has pointer semantics.  @Suever's answer appears to have your desired behavior.  Please clarify with a more illustrative example if it is lacking.

Comment: @TroyHaskin See the edit and the new last line of the code

Comment: Keep in mind that unless the class is modified within the calling function, MATLAB will not produce a copy inline with its lazy-copying methodology.

Comment: @TroyHaskin I know that, but I do need to modify the copy inside the function, that's the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your class is a value class (MATLAB's default). If you want to be able to pass objects around by reference (changes will be reflected in the original object), you'll to make it a [handle class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html) by subclassing `handle`

```
classdef MyClass < handle
    properties
        arr
        accessHandle
    end

    methods
        function obj = MyClass(array, trans)
            obj.arr = array;
            obj.accessHandle = @(i) obj.arr(trans(i))
        end
    end
end
```

And then you can use it the way you expect

```
m = MyClass([1 2 3], @(x)x);

m.accessHandle(2)
%   2

m.arr(2) = 5;

m.accessHandle(2)
%   5
```

More information about the difference between the two [can be found here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html).

**Edit**

If you need `MyClass` to be a value class, then you could store the `trans` value as a property and then have a normal method to access the value

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
        arr
        trans
    end

    methods
        function obj = MyClass(array, trans)
            obj.arr = array;
            obj.trans = trans;
        end

        function res = access(obj, k)
            res = obj.arr(obj.trans(k));
        end
    end
end
```

Or if you want, you could make `accessHandle` a dependent property that returns a function handle.

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
        arr
        trans
    end

    properties (Dependent)
        accessHandle
    end

    methods
        function obj = MyClass(array, trans)
            obj.arr = array;
            obj.trans = trans;
        end

        function res = get.accessHandle(obj)
            res = @(i)obj.arr(obj.trans(i));
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: See the edit, the class should be a value class, the change is only for the definition of `accessHandle`

Comment: @OmerRosler Why does it need to be a value class? You can't do that without having a handle class.

Comment: @OmerRosler Also why can't you just pass the object into the `accessHandle` anonymous function?

Comment: @OmerRosler Or just make `accessHandle` a real method

Comment: Well, the class is an array with wierd way to access data, it has the semantics of a value class; the access function is what requires a handle to the class, not the class itself

Comment: Because it makes a copy of the object in the constructor, and if I change the array later on, it won't change at all inside `accessHandle`

Comment: @OmerRosler I've provided two alternatives if you need a value class

Comment: Great! Iused a variant of your example: I saved an `impl_access` as a variable which is defined as `@(arr)@(x) arr(trans(x))`, and the get method of `accessHandle` returns `impl_access(obj.arr)`